# 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

Error:
[js] 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I have set `"checkJS": true` and `"jsx": "react"` in jsconfig.json. This is not for ts.

```
async function readAsArrayBuffer(blob) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         let reader = new FileReader();
         // @ts-ignore
        reader.addEventListener('load', e => resolve((e.target).result));
         // @ts-ignore
        reader.addEventListener('error', e => reject((e.target).error));
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
}
```

Script ofcourse working good.

How do I fix this unnecessary error?

Comment: Is there anything here that could help? I do not know how, and whether or not?
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript

Comment: tip: If you want a promise/arrayBuffer construct a new [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/Response) and call `arrayBuffer()`: `new Response(blob).arrayBuffer()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you need to target es6 or use a polyfill.  I don't use VisualStudio but it looks like the following addition to your config might enable es6:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { "target": "ES6" },
    //....
}
```

Comment: What you gave helped to the problem with Promise. But it created a different problem: with loading node_modules modules and modules without extensions and modules loaded through a folder (where you enter folderpath and loads the index.js file from this folder).

And these are the react-app functions, as far as I understand.
At least I have to load modules from node_modules somehow.

Comment: @lukaszpolowczyk You might look at `baseUrl` and `paths` under `compilerOptions`. Otherwise, you might want to start a new question and provide additional details.

Comment: Or maybe it can be set somehow, so that Promise simply does not display such an error? Something like this, I just do not know how to use it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript

Comment: I solved the problem with the modules using `" moduleResolution ":" node "`. Now there are no errors. Phew.